# Subset sum to 0/1 knapsack

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, np-complete, np-hard, np

How can I translate (i.e. reduce) an arbitrary instance $(S, t)$ of Subset Sum into an instance of 0-1 Knapsack? I'm also given a hint: you may assume that all members of $S$ are positive integers.

Answer (score 1):

Set the size of the bag to the value you are trying to reach $t$. For each element $x \in S$ add one item to the set having both its weight and value equal to $x$. The claim is the $(S, t)$ is a yes instance of the subset sums problem if and only if the optimal value of the bag is equal to $t$ (why?).